# Erlang - Will more fragments in Mnesia mean more performance?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a table in mnesia and read that the size limit of a table is only 4gb. I read that to store more data in a single table, fragmentation has to be done in mnesia. Also when using a table without fragmentation I noted that the cpu usage is high(disc_only_copies) not sure why though.

I wanted to know if adding more fragments will improve mnesia performance, reduce the cpu usage or is it just to store more data in a single table?

Comment: I don't see why fragmentation it should make much difference. Check your CPU is not busy in IOWAIT rather than doing something useful.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what kind of table you use:

**disk_only:**  uses DETS and is limited to 2GB (don't use this!)

**ram_copies:** only in RAM (ETS table) limited to < 4 GB on 32bit machines, much larger possible on 64bit Erlang VMs limited by available memory

**disk_copies:** in RAM and in a transaction log on disk, doesn't have DETS limitations but the RAM limitations remain, but if you have enough RAM and use a 64bit VM you are fine

for more details see: [LYSE on mnesia table types](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/mnesia#from-record-to-table)